# Edit approval window makes no sense

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits

As of today, I am entitled to approving edits. Twice now I have encountered edits that made no sense at all. Specifically, strings are inserted that I don't believe an editor would have put in there at all. I believe there is a bug somewhere. Here is a screenshot:[image]
What is going on here? I will `skip` this edit, as I did the previous one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Feel free in the future to "reject" edits like this as an "invalid edit" (or even "vandalism" if it really massacres the original content).

---

From the brilliant Jorge: it is a review audit to see if you pay attention!
So you would have passed if you followed my answer :-D

Comment: Are you saying that this is not a bug, but a deliberate attempt to mess things up? Or is the editing system flawed in some known way?

Comment: Good question. I asssume this is deliberate :) But if it is a bug the edit needs to be reversed anyways so tagging it is the best course.

Comment: Thank you. BTW good band name: Gnome Gnome Org and the Edits.

Comment: [this](http://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/289030) is a fairly wacky edit - where on earth they got that from I don't know...

Comment: Maybe it's an audit review test?

Comment: @JorgeCastro That finally dawned on me, too, after I did what Rinzwind suggested and I "passed". Not very subtle, though.

Comment: @Jos They're mostly just there to make sure you are paying attention. There are people who will just sit there clicking approve on every single edit as soon as they can. Those people won't notice the obvious ;-)

Comment: ah dang of course those audit review test got me again. I failed again _O- @JorgeCastro :D

Answer (score 1):

This has been a test of the <strike>emergency broadcast</strike> Stack Exchange Review Audit system. We use this to prevent "roboreviews" AKA people trying to just review a bunch of stuff for badges etc. You have bypassed the audit by skipping the question, which is fine. If you had approved the edit, you'd have **failed** the test. The punishment for failure is very minor at first (nothing bad happens initially) and compounds over time if you continue to fail really frequently.

Just make sure to always pay attention to reviews and choose an appropriate action (such as reject for nonsense edits). When you don't know what to do, Skip (as you did) is a safe bet!

Now you know, and knowing is half the battle.

[image: G.I. Joeeeeeeeee!!!!!]

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. How exactly have I failed? I noticed the suspicous edit, found it too improbable to be deliberate, therefore I clicked `skip`. No punishment, no "Stop, Look and Listen!" page appeared as if I had pressed "Looks OK".

Comment: My answer is mostly in jest. The system would have expected you to reject a nonsense edit. If you didn't know what to do (as was the case here), skip is safe, so you didn't really fail. Failure would have been accepting the edit. [See more details here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/262550)

Comment: @Jos I have also clarified my answer. Sorry that it wasn't very clear at first. Friday afternoon...